# USB 3.0 ports don't work with Windows 10

Tags: drivers, windows-10, usb-3

I installed Windows 10 on my computer (no upgrade) and my USB 3.0 ports don't work. The USB 2.0 ports instead work properly. On another hard drive (same computer) I'm running Windows 7. There they work.

How do I get the USB 3.0 ports working on Windows 10? I think I need drivers for them but how do I know where I get them? Can Windows show me which drivers I need?

Comment: You can get the driver from your OEM's support website.

Comment: Check your motherboard's model ([Speccy](https://www.piriform.com/speccy) should help) and look for driver on manufacturer's website.