# USB wireless headphones disappear from devices list

Tags: windows-10, usb-3

I recently bought a pair of wireless headphones (**NOX KROM KUPRA**). After plugging in the headphones, the headphones and microphone both appear under playback devices and recording devices, and both disappear roundabout 5 seconds after.

I have tried disabling Realtek, and updating said drivers, both of which with no success. It is worth noting that the same issue only happens on another PC when using 3.0 ports.

**Update:** The headphones started working on another Windows 10 PC.

**Update:** USB 2.0 Hub made no difference.

**Update:** The USB 2.0 Hub makes a difference on another computer with USB 3.0 ports. It however, makes no difference in the intended computer.

**Update:**  Updating the USB driver didn't help.

Comment: Try disabling XHCI support in the BIOS, or connect the headphones to a USB 2.0 hub.

Comment: I cannot find XHCI, please note I'm using UEFI and running an AMD processor.

Comment: So you're saying the problem appears to be using the headphones with a combination of USB 3.0 and Win 10?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the problem.

Comment: [Another question reporting a problem with USB 3.0 and Win 10](http://superuser.com/questions/963524/usb-3-0-ports-dont-work-with-windows-10).  Advice was to update the driver.  Worth a shot.

Comment: @fixer1234 No luck.

Comment: Couldn't hurt to check the battery in the headphones.

Comment: The headphones are fully charged, as they work on my laptop. Also, even when disconnected from the wireless station, the headphones should appear, as they do on the laptop.